# How to add new div at 4th position if we have 6 div already with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

**How to add new div at 4th position if we have 6 div already with same class name**

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following using [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method

```
$('div').eq(2).after($('<div/>'));
```

or using the [`:eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
$('div:eq(2)').after($('<div/>'));
```